# Tab completion within quotes?

Tags: git, bash, gnu, tab-completion

In my `GNU bash, version 4.3.11` I am using git and sometimes in comments I want to mention the files I changed. When doing so, I try to use the tab completion, so that I just have to type the first characters of the file name and then get it auto completed with the tab:

So I say:

```
git add README.md
```

And then

```
git commit -m "Modified RE
#                         ^
#                         here I press tab and nothing happens
```

However, it doesn't get expanded because it is within quotes. Instead, this does work:

```
git commit -m "Modified" RE
#                          ^
#                          here I press tab so that I get README.md
```

So is what I end up doing: closing the quotes, completing with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, removing the previous quote and appending it to the end of the comment I wrote. This is a bit tiring, so I wonder:

Is there any way to get the tab completion working within quotes?

Comment: How should the tab completion distinguish between `"Modified Re<tab>` and `"Read M<tab>` when completing inside quotes? Where a file in cwd is called `Read Me.txt` and another called `Modules`?

Comment: @andlrc uhms, this is a good point I hadn't thought about, and probably the reason why tab-completion within quotes is not possible.

Comment: I think it already works inside quotes, but not on a word basic, but rater on the whole thing: `"Modified RE<tab>` -> searches cwd for files matching `"Modified RE"*`

Comment: @andlrc true. So the workaround may be to open the quotes, use tab-completion with the name, move back and prepend the comment. That is, `git commit -m "RE<tab>` to get `git commit -m "README.md"` and then move back to write before README.md.

Comment: That is a workaround, but I don't like it to much: `git commit -m "Modified" RE<Tab><M-b><M-b><backspace><backspace><space>`

Comment: What about writing your command from within a text editor with an omni completion feature and then sending the command to the shell?

Comment: @andlrc what does `<M-b>` mean?

Comment: @LittleNooby what I later on thought on is to use a variable for the file, since this is expanded within double quotes: `file="README.md"; git add "$file"; git commit -m "Something done in $file"`.

Comment: @StefanHegny the `git commit -m "Modified "RE<tab>` approach doesn't work to me :/ I need to add a space after the last `"` and then I enter in the backspace orgia again.

Comment: When you install `git` a set of functions are installed into a directory that can be used by the common `bash-completion` package (if it is installed). If you are using this package, you could try modifying one of those functions.

Comment: Oops hadn't tried it actually, sorry

Comment: M-b is backward-word; M aka meta is commonly alt or, on really old systems Esc.

Comment: @tripleee ah right, now I see [Commands For Moving in the Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html). For this I do `<Ctrl> + <left arrow>`.

Comment: @tripleee Or with i3 where <Alt> is bound to other stuff. aka <Esc> ftw :-)

Comment: Yeah, I use Esc just because of habit. There was a trme when I used Emacs over a genuine VT220 every day. But I was beginning to think I was alone in the world.